# insert read-only multilingual text to user registration form

Tags: forms, i18n-l10n

I've added a 'Term of use' read-only description into the Drupal user registration form, but I would like to make it **multilingual**.
The corresponding code is in the begin of template.php (responsive is the theme name):

```
function responsive_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
switch($form_id) { 
case 'user_register_form': // the value we stole from the rendered form 
$multi_regform = array(
'‪#‎type‬' => 'checkbox',
'‪#‎title‬' => t("Elfogadom a moderálási elveket"),
'‪#‎description‬' => t("A Magyar Térinformatikai Társaság (HUNAGI) hivatalos honlapján való publikálás és kommentelés lehetőségét a HUNAGI regisztrált tagjai ..... A közzététellel a regisztrált felhasználó lemond a bejegyzés feletti rendelkezés jogáról, későbbiekben anyagi vagy más jellegű követeléseket ezekre alapozva nem támaszthat. - A HUNAGI vezetősége - "),
'‪#‎required‬' => TRUE,
'‪#‎localize‬' => TRUE, // Does not function...
'‪#‎weight‬' => 1, // Adjust so that you can place it whereever 
);
$form['terms_of_use'] = $multi_regform;
break; 
} 
}
```

You can check it here: http://hunagi.hu/hu/user/register

Now the text is Hungarian, can I add an English one someway?

*ps: I've already tried this by Field addition by Field Group, Field Permissions modules, that did not work.*

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to translate your strings at `admin/config/regional/translate/translate`, just search a word contained in the two hungarian strings (case sensitive!), click on the edit link of the relevant string and you should be done.

Comment: hmm, I've found the text and added some text in other languages, but it doesn't appear : (